# Does the real line mean that the start and end points of any line must exist?

Tags: existence, time, self, numbers

> In mathematics, a real number is a value of a continuous quantity that
>   can represent a distance along a line

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number

> We consider  the  set  of real  numbers,  denoted  by R,  as  the 
>   points  on  an  infinite straight line – called the real line– on which
>   we have fixed two different points, say “0” and “1”.  We consider the
>   distance between 0 and 1 as one unit, and therefore, the points 0 and 1
>   define a measure on the real line.  This measure has also a
>   direction,namely from 0 to 1, denoted~01, thus, the distance between
>   two points can also be negative.  Further, we identify a point on the
>   real line with its distance to 0 (with respect to the measure~01) and
>   this distance is called a real number.

http://user.math.uzh.ch/halbeisen/4students/pdf/1-4.pdf

This basic maths suggests that we can't have real numbers without a real line.

But also there are no gaps in a real line. Does that mean that any point along any line must exist, including its start and end points?

---

I'm asking because I don't understand how the point instant of my death (at the end of life) can be said to exist. But I don't explain that, in order to stay on topic.

Comment: This isn’t a philosophical question on the philosophy of mathematics. You might want to ask this very basic question on Math.SE.

Comment: there's no need to downvote for that reason @MoziburUllah ! feel free to migrate it tho!

Comment: do you know the answer @MoziburUllah ? it's clearly a question about existence anyway so i don't think it's suitable for the math SE

Comment: I did down-vote and why not if I disapprove of it? That’s the whole point of down-voting. If you do migrate to Math.SE you might want to clean it of it’s conceptual salad-dressing otherwise they may throw it out there too.

Comment: you're picking and choosing! does philosophy SE not ask about "existence"? @MoziburUllah and do you know the answer?

Comment: Can you expand on why you don't understand how the instant of your death can exist?  The fact that you are asking such a question suggests that others do not seem to have a problem with this concept, but you do.  Given that we are "others," it may help to explain what about the concept bothers you.

Comment: it's not a refined intuition @CortAmmon just seems that anything that is in my present will be in my past. do dead people have pasts?

Comment: Ahh, so you're having issues with the continuity of things around your death.  As a test case, do you think I should have any issue with the idea of the instant of *your* death? I might have an issue with the instant of my own death, but the instant of another individual should be simpler.

Comment: @Another_name: it’s a conceptual word salad that I don’t think anybody but you and a few other thought-free others will be interested in.

Comment: it's nothing of the sort man, stop being so quick witted @MoziburUllah

Comment: @another_name: Just because you’ve found someone else that wants to go on a conceptual spin along with you doesn’t mean that the question is actually worth anything. My vote stands - whether you like it or not.

Comment: i can kinda just tell that you've rushed to misunderstand @MoziburUllah

Comment: @another_name: Have you heard about brain-storming? It was invented by an advertising executive. Looking at its rules - no criticism was allowed and everyone has to take on board positively what someone else says. It’s capitalisms answer to thinking - that is philosophy and science. This is not how philosophy, science or mathematics  is done.

Comment: i think that's what you are doing. what don't you understand? @MoziburUllah i apologize if i haven't read enough philosophy to ask a "basic question"!

Comment: It makes little sense to mix "existentialism" with *real* numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really two questions here.  One is a pure math question "do real numbers exist without the real number line?"  The answer is most certainly yes.  The properties of real numbers can be defined in a way completely independent of geometry.  The number line is merely a simple geometric construct which can be used to explain some of those properties.

As for "do the start and end points exist," the study of real numbers includes the concept of an open or closed end-point.  You are permitted to use open sets of points to capture the idea of a set of points that does not include its end point.

So when it comes to the instant of your death, it is not unreasonable to say that your subjective concept of time is open at the instant of your death -- you can describe what happens up to that point, but not at that point.  However, if there exists an objective observer (or a subjective observe who outlives you), they may be able to talk about the instant of your death.

Comment: that's great, thanks for the answer!

Comment: There is no "philosophy" here... If we model the "time line" with the continuum of the "geometric line" a human life is simply a *segment* with start- and end-point. No "philosophy of mathematics" involved, neither "deep meaning" about existence.

Comment: yeah it's mostly maths, but you can see why i thought it might not be @MauroALLEGRANZA ?

Comment: @another_name - Your attempt to link the nature of time, the real numbers and the instant of death seems a little off-beam to me, but it also seems like a valuable way to think about these things and usefully philosophical. It all comes down to the nature of the Continuum, on which topic you might like to read Hermann Weyl.